# etcd --experimental-corrupt-check-time seems to have no effect even if db and 000*.wal files are corrupted on a single node?

Tags: nosql, cluster-computing, corruption, etcd

I run 3 nodes etcd cluster with additional flag `--experimental-corrupt-check-time 1m`. Flag itself does work, so I could see log messages from the Leader:

```
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-07-17T13:23:13.603Z","caller":"etcdserver/corrupt.go:259","msg":"finished peer corruption check","number-of-peers-checked":2}
```

I wished to test that feature and made following operations on the third node only:

```
echo "Hello World" > etcd/member/wal/0000000000000000-0000000000000000.wal
echo "Hello World" >> etcd/member/snap/db
```

As you can see both `db` and `*.wal` are, from now on, not consistent across a cluster.

I expect that etcd will raise `CORRUPT_ALARM` accoring to documentaion, but nothing actually happend I still see `NO ALARMS` on each node as well as successfull "corruption check" by etcd, which logs out:

```
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-07-17T13:23:13.603Z","caller":"etcdserver/corrupt.go:259","msg":"finished peer corruption check","number-of-peers-checked":2}
```

Please also note that I run 3 nodes cluster and all 3 are healthy and do respond. But `"number-of-peers-checked":2` is still 2, though...